# Is the better solution create classes for each file xml?

Tags: android

I create a simple app with a start menu and an other page.
I have connected them with a button and i have write the function in the same file java. I would know if It is the right solution or not.

Comment: this is entirely subjective, and will depend on a lot more factors than you've listed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in the oficial documentation : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html.

According the best practices, you have to declare one xml layout for each activity or fragment.

Comment: That would depend on your design.